# How do I search for a list of files using wildcard

Tags: c#, wildcard

How do I use wildcards in C# to list down files contained in a selected folder?

Comment: Could you explain what you want to do a little better please?

Listing the files whose filenames match your string or some other thing?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

[`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles.aspx) is your friend here:

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Me\Documents", "*.docx");
```

or, recursively:

```
Directory.GetFiles(
    @"C:\Users\Me\Documents",
    "*.docx",
    SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Answer (score 24):

Use [`DirectoryInfo.GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
using System.IO;

DirectoryInfo folder = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\foo\bar");
if (folder.Exists) // else: Invalid folder!
{
    FileInfo[] files = folder.GetFiles("*.xml");

    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
        DoSomething(file.FullName);
    }
}
```

Comment: folder.GetFiles() returns a string[] not a FileInfo[] so this don't work. Very confusing for newbs! or am i missing a subtlety?

Comment: @jolyon: No, not a string[]. See docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: jolyon's comment is incorrect and confusing so I wanted to clarify. new DirectoryInfo().GetFiles returns FolderInfo[] and Directory.GetFiles returns string[]

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like this:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\myfolder", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```