# c# searching on C:\Users\John\Desktop using the text on text.box as search key?

Tags: c#, search, textbox

I need to make a simple windows form application in C#, that when I type something in a textbox, the program will search for the words in a path.  For example, `C:\Users\John\Desktop` using the "text" in the textbox as the search key.

Example

```
text in textbox = "room"
```

The program will search for the "room" on the desktop.

> Possible output : (room202.swf) any file extension as long as the
>   search key is on the name.

I hope I made myself clear.. if you have questions regarding this feel free to ask.

Comment: Just to be clear, by 'desktop' do you mean the actual desktop or the file system as well?

Comment: My question to you is: what have you tried?

Comment: And I need a Porsche, can you help me ? :)

Comment: [How do I search for a list of files using wildcard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584711/how-do-i-search-for-a-list-of-files-using-wildcard) & [How to get a path to the desktop for current user in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634142/how-to-get-a-path-to-the-desktop-for-current-user-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below should work. It enumerates that path. Be sure to have a multiline textbox called txtOutput, and a txtSearch named control. You can put this in a button click or where ever.

```
 txtOutput.Text = "";

 foreach(string file in Directory.GetFiles("c:\\path"))
    if(Path.GetFileName(file).Contains(txtSearch.Text))
        txtOutput.Text += txtOutput.Text + file + ", ";
```

Comment: thanks a lot! this helps me.. but can i ask 1 more question ? how can i access the searched file .. if its a video, or a music .. can i play it on the form1 i make? thanks again!

Comment: You can indeed just use Process.Start(filename). This is specified in the docs for Process.Start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This code contains some of the basic functionality that you can use to search your directory

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string [] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\path");

    foreach(string fn in fileNames)
    {
        if(Path.GetFileName(fn).Contains(textBox1.Text))
        {
            //do something with fn
        }
    }
}
```

for more information, read up on the [System.IO Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: im sorry, can i ask something, how can i search the text on textbox1?

im sorry for asking .. thanks for the help.

Comment: @JurelJacinto you can search using text from just about anywhere

Comment: @JurelJacinto i've edited the answer to use `textBox1`

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\John\Desktop", "*" + textBox1.Text + "*");
foreach(string file in files)
{
    // Output file to user somewhere
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
string strToSearch "room";
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path , "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

 foreach(string fl in files)
    {
        if(Path.GetFileName(fl).Contains(strToSearch))
        {
            // Do the magic here
        }
    }
```

1. Here `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);` will give you the path for desktop.
2. Use this to get all file paths in the desktop `Directory.GetFiles(path ,"*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);`