# how to write the code for finding the videos names and extensions and has to convert into another extension using C# if we giving the path

Tags: c#

how to find the videos name and extensions if we given the path of where videos are present if the path may contains one or more videos also

```
protected void button_click()
{
  string path=textbox.Text;
}
```

Comment: Look at the DirectoryInfo and FileInfo classes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I search for a list of files using wildcard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584711/how-do-i-search-for-a-list-of-files-using-wildcard)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Directory.GetFiles**

```
Directory.GetFiles(textbox.Text, "*.mp4");
```

If You want to have the recursive call in all the sub folders then use

```
Directory.GetFiles(textbox.Text, "*.mp4", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

This can be easily found on the web. Anyways, I hope this may help. Please do some research before posting the question.