# improve way of testing in C# if file format matches any in list

Tags: c#

In short I'm building a treeview like structure of nodes. I'm looping through each folder and each file within the folder looking for specific file formats. I know the function im using for IsValidFileFormat is not ideal. I want to be able to pass it list of fileformats such as {.txt, .ms, .png} and upon first test returning true it returns True. That way it doesn't continue looping through the other formats if it doesn't need to.

The below example loops through each directory using a try catch so it doesn't error on folders which don't have permission.

```
// tests if given filepath has a compatible extension
static bool IsValidFileType(string filename)
{
    bool results = false;

    string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);
    // add multiple acceptable file extensions 
    if (string.Equals(".mse", ext, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) return true;
    if (string.Equals(".ms", ext, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) return true;

    return results;
}

public static TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
  {
      var directoryNode = new TreeNode(directoryInfo.Name);

      foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
      {
          try
          {
              // ignore direcotories which start with an 'underscore'
              if (!directory.Name.StartsWith("_"))
              {
              directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory));
              }
          }
          catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { }
      }
      foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
      {
          if (IsValidFileType(file.FullName))
          {
              TreeNode node = new TreeNode(file.Name, 1, 1);
              node.Tag = file.FullName;
              node.ForeColor = toolColor;
              directoryNode.Nodes.Add(node);

              // add to global fileList which is used for searches
              fileList.Add(file.FullName);
          }
      }
      // if (directoryNode.Nodes.Count != 0)
      return directoryNode;
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I search for a list of files using wildcard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584711/how-do-i-search-for-a-list-of-files-using-wildcard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you really need to do is create a `list` or `array` (etc) to hold the acceptable file types, then `break` as soon as you hit one.

```
static bool IsValidFileType(string filename)
{
    bool results = false;
    string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);

    List<string> fileTypes = new List<string>();

    fileTypes.Add("exe");
    fileTypes.Add("mse");
    //etc

    for (int i = 0; i < fileTypes.Count; i++)
    {
        if (ext == fileTypes[i])
        {
            results = true;
            break;

            //or just return true;
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

You could also move this list/array/whatever out to the class level and use the same list for different methods.

You can also use a `LINQ` query to acheive the same result:

`results = fileTypes.Any(fileType => fileType.Equals(ext));`

This will look through the list of fileTypes and return true if any match the right side of `=>` -- In this case, `String.Equals(ext)`.

Note that the `LINQ` method will return an `ArgumentNullException` if either `fileTypes` or `ext` is null, so if they CAN be null, make sure you check that first.

**EDIT:** If using the `LINQ` method, you'll still need to test for case. You can do that in a few different ways:

- Your current method, using an overload of `String.Equals`: `... => fileType.Equals(ext, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));`
- In-line: `results = fileTypes.Any(fileType => fileType.ToLower().Equals(ext.ToLower()));`
- Same as above, but set the variable `ext` to lower case: '`string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename).ToLower();`
- etc.

Personally I think the `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` is the cleaner way, the other methods are kind of ugly.

Comment: does linq ignore case sensitive?

Comment: @JokerMartini sorry about that, you should still test for case. I have updated the post. The LINQ method in this case is essentially just a shorter way of writing the `for` loop, `String.Equals` still cares about case.

Comment: you see super knowledgable and helpful with this. Would you be open to helping me out with another question. I can post or message you.

Comment: @JokerMartini actually, I'm very much a junior developer who's been exposed to this for the past 6 months or so ... disclaimer on anything I tell you! You're welcome to shoot me a message, I'd be happy to try to help out.

Comment: looks like you can't send direct messages on here. my gmail is jokermartini@gmail.com

Answer (score 3):

you could make an extension method like this:-

```
public static IEnumerable<FileInfo> GetFilesByExtensions(this DirectoryInfo dir,
 params string[] extensions)
{
    if (extensions == null) 
         throw new ArgumentNullException("extensions");
    IEnumerable<FileInfo> files = dir.EnumerateFiles();
    return files.Where(f => extensions.Contains(f.Extension));
}
```

and the use that like :

`directoryInfo.GetFilesByExtensions(".ms",".mse")`

which will return only the files you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

How are you fetching list of files? You can use `Directory.EnumerateFiles Method (String, String, SearchOption)` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571(v=vs.110).aspx and use the searchPattern parameter. You just need to call it for every extension then concat the lists. This is an enumeration so it will only load the file info as you request it.

Note: you can also use Directory.GetFiles https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx to load them immediately.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your questions correctly, you want your "IsValidFileType" function to accept a list of acceptable formats and see if a file matches one of them.  You also want "true" returned at the first match.  This should work:

```
static bool IsValidFileType(string filename, List<string> AcceptableExtensions)
{
    string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);

    foreach (string AccExt in AcceptableExtensions)
         if (ext.ToUpper() == AccExt.ToUpper())
              return true;

    return false;
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
  List<string> AcceptableExtensions = new List<string>();
  AcceptableExtensions.Add(".mse");
  AcceptableExtensions.Add(".ms");

  foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
  {
      if (IsValidFileType(file.FullName, AcceptableExtensions))
      {
          TreeNode node = new TreeNode(file.Name, 1, 1);
          node.Tag = file.FullName;
          node.ForeColor = toolColor;
          directoryNode.Nodes.Add(node);

          // add to global fileList which is used for searches
          fileList.Add(file.FullName);
      }
  }
```